# Executing stored procedure won't work on production server, permissions missing?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I'm having some trouble with a stored procedure I'm running through PHP and I've been scratching my (and tech support's) head for four days straight now. Perhaps you can help shed some light on this.

In brief: I have a stored procedure defined on my local computer (`spcTest`). A PHP-page can run it without a problem, so that it returns a single-row recordset. When I re-create the procedure on the production server, the PHP-page doesn't get the same results.

I'm pretty sure this is a permissions-issue, but I'm having a hard time pinpointing it. I have access to the production server through phpMyAdmin and that's where I run all my creation scripts. I also see the stored procedure spcTest show up on production (using `SELECT * FROM ROUTINES`) and I can also update it successfully.

When I run the following command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR triis@localhost;
```

these are the results I get on the development server and the production server, respectively:

~~~=== On the development server ===~~~

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'triis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F05[~~(snip)~~]72'

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tri_is`.* TO 'triis'@'localhost'
```

~~~=== On the production server ===~~~

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'triis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F05[~~(snip)~~]72'

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tri_is`.* TO 'triis'@'localhost'
```

Note the difference in the `GRANT USAGE`-line on which does not exist on the development side. I've been through the mySQL documentation but may have missed the answer... in short, my question is: do the privileges on the production server as they appear above, allow for execution of any stored procedures including `spcTest`?

To me, it doesn't look like the user `triis` should have permission to execute because the `EXECUTE`-attribute isn't mentioned specifically. But seeing as the `SHOW GRANTS`-command returns strikingly similar results on production and development servers (especially `ALL PRIVILEGES` on both sides) I'm a little confused why the PHP-code would work on the development-side only.

If this turns out to be a permissions-issue on production, would something like `GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, EXECUTE ON * TO triis@'localhost'` help in giving execution rights for this and any future stored procedure?

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: If your SP is defined in the `tri_is` database, on which your user has all permissions, you should certainly be able to execute it.

Comment: So ALL PRIVILEGES includes EXECUTE? I think I read somewhere that you had to explicitly grant access to executing a stored procedure (in this case to 'triis'), even if ''triis' is the user who creates it.

Comment: [*The `ALL` or `ALL PRIVILEGES` privilege specifier is shorthand. It stands for “all privileges available at a given privilege level” (except `GRANT OPTION`). For example, granting `ALL` at the global or table level grants all global privileges or all table-level privileges.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_all). You have `ALL` at the database level:  [*Table or routine privileges also can be specified at the database level, in which case they apply to all tables or routines in the database.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges)

Comment: Thanks @eggyal for pointing me away from permissions. I created a very simple script with the same building blocks as my procedure has and traced through it, step by step.

What I found was this: in an `UPDATE`-statement within my SP, a table name was provided as **p_productGroup**, and when ran the `UPDATE`-statement separately, I got an error saying that there was no such table to be found. Apparently, the table name is case-sensitive but the SP wasn't returning errors (simply failing, but still running OK with 0 rows returned).

Comment: I didn't think table names were case sensitive except if they were enclosed within back ticks at `CREATE`. I went back to check, and found that the table was created using `p_productgroup` enclosed in backticks. Case sensitive!

I wrote the SQL without the back ticks, but at one point exported the whole database on the production server using myPhpAdmin and re-created all tables. In that exported file, back ticks were added, enforcing the case sensitivity that ensued.

On my development machine, however, this case sensitivity wasn't an issue. Time to review some scripts!

Comment: Beware that case sensitivity is down to more than just backticks: the filesystem on which MySQL's data files are stored is [very relevant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).  Also, be aware that [`SHOW WARNINGS;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-warnings.html) may have helped to track down this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't a permissions-issue as I originally thought, but an error occurring in an `UPDATE`-statement running inside a stored procedure (`SP`).

The error stemmed from case sensitivity of the table name (being updated), and the mismatch of casing on development and production environment. The stored procedure didn't report the error directly when run in **phpMyAdmin** and I didn't have resources to run it on the production server in the mySQL shell to further investigate. Running the `SP` in PHP to diagnose didn't help, and while appearing to have full permissions to run `SP`s on both environments and still only getting results on the development side only had me baffled.

**Lesson of the day:** although backticks are a pain to type (at least on an Icelandic keyboard), it's good practice to include them right off the bat. The other option is not using camel-casing in your table names or procedures. Generating mySQL-scripts through phpMyAdmin will add the ticks and case-sensitivity will follow. Running the generated scripts on only one of your environments can cause troubles with scripts that are still under development (and not a part of the generated batch).